# Why can't I straighten a loop of vertices to Z axis?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, scale

I'm confused: I can't get a freaking loop cut in vertex mode straight.
I do S+Z+0 and nothing happens. I cleared scale Alt+S, applied all transformations, and still nothing. Does anyone know what is this all about?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *On Cage* option of your *Subdivision Surface* modifier is activated, so your edge loop may appear a bit tilted while it's actually not, as the option will twist the edges to fit their transformation through the modifier. So just deactivate the option and check the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You are absolutely right. Case closed.